# How do I use newly installed modules in React when they do not appear in the package.json "dependencies" list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, package.json

[Updated my question to give more details]

I am quite new at working with React so this maybe a basic question.  I installed several modules I will use one as an example for clarity which was `@react-google-maps/api`

In my PCs terminal I wrote the following for the install:

```
npm i -S @react-google-maps/api
```

When I check in the terminal using:

```
npm ls --depth=0
```

I see the module is present in the list it returns.  (I have Node.js version 16.14.2 and npm version 8.11.0)

When I open my React app (created using the create-react-app template) I do not see the module listed under dependencies or in the node-modules list.

Since I am some trouble using the contents of this module I was hoping someone might advise if there is something I did wrong in the install or need to do before trying to import components from it.

Comment: How did you install the modules and what version of NodeJS and npm are you using?

Comment: You could try to import and use them as usual. If a problem arises, might try to remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and try reinstalling them again.

Comment: If you did `npm install` them, they should show up in your `package.json`.

Comment: I am using npm version 8.11.0 and NodeJS version 16.14.2

Comment: One of the modules that I was trying to install was @react-google-maps/api and I followed the install instructions to install it as follows `npm i -S @react-google-maps/api`

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details. Can you find `@react-google-maps/api` in the `package.json` and in `node_modules`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly this happens all the time to me -- not knowing much about your local environment, I would wager that you're likely not in your project's directory and are probably installing it globally.

If you're using VS code, you can just open the terminal in it, but if you're not go ahead and move to the directory that is at the same root level as your package.json. Then do your npm install [DEPENDENCY YOU WANT]

It should work!

Comment: Thanks, installing direct in the VS Code terminal did the trick!  (I must have installed it originally in global like you said.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an npm version before version 5, it was necessary to add `--save` (or `-S`) option when installing modules to add them to `package.json` (eg. `npm install --save lodash`).